# Azure Servicebus Message Audit

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

Is it possible to capture a copy of each message and forward it to another queue or storage with the build-in ASB functionality?
Like the nservicebus does but using the native ASB sdk.

If no build-in functionality exists, what would be a good approach to solve this?
I would like to avoid giving the client-code (or client wrapper) the responsibility of sending a copy to a separate queue.

It would be optimal to have a separate "service" that could listen to messages and capture a copy?
I guess we could create a separate subscription for each topic and do this.

But what about queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in option available for backing up the messages in Service Bus Queue, but Service Bus Standard Client allows you to create Plugins for solving problems like this. There is already a plugin available for [backing up the messages in Azure Table Storage](https://github.com/davidrevoledo/ServiceBus.LogginPlugin/).

Comment: Yes it possible to make a plugin to the servicebus. Just like impl IMessageAuditStore using Masstransit. But both models require that you change the client/sender code. It would be nice with an "interceptor" on a lower level. Just like SQL Server Audit / Change Tracking etc.

Comment: I don’t think such capability is available rigjt now with the Queues

Answer (score 0):

Just like was already answered, this functionality is not provided by the client.

This kind of functionality would need to be custom built. Using a plugin can have challenges as there's not transactional guarantee around sent out messages. Original message could fail while the audit message would succeed.

Ideally, this would be a **broker** (server-side) feature.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, I would like to avoid a client side solution. But with the lack of this feature as a server side feature, I assume that it easy to implement by subscribing to each Topic and persist each message. I also assume that this will only work for Topics and not queues.

Comment: Here's the issue. NServiceBus audit indicates a messages _has been receved and processed_. A broker based audit would indicate a message _has been delivered / consumed_. A topology (catch all subscription on topics) would indicate a message _has been delivered *only*_. So not quite the same.